# Splitting and iterating on all over instance and return two items

Tags: python

I am splitting x variable (string)  in based on `*` and then `;` and return out 
all info.  I tried so for below and it give only `own1` info.

so basically I want to split and iterating on all over instance and return two items which will then go into `OS.Path.Join(path,own1,OwnAdd1)` to make folder/subfolder

```
x= 'own1;own1Add*own2;ownAdd2*own3:ownAdd'

def cleanAndMakeSubfolder(x) :
   for x in  x.split("*"):

    Owner= x.split(";")  [0].replace(" ","_").strip()
    count = x.split(";")[1].count(" ")-1
    OwnerADD =  x.split(";")[1].replace(",","_") .replace(" ","_",count).replace('"',"").replace("(","").strip()
    return Owner,OwnerADD
print cleanAndMakeSubfolder(x)
```

Comment: This is a total mess, but try `re.split(';|\*|:', x)` to split everything and then just iterate.

Comment: You're only getting the first set of results because you're returning immediately after you parse it. None of the rest get a chance to run.

Comment: @glibdud Any clues how to solve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) to split on multiple delimiters and then iterate through the `splitted` two at a time:

```
import re
import os

path = 'some_path'
x = 'own1;own1Add*own2;ownAdd2*own3;ownAdd'
splitted = re.split(';|\*',x)

for x, y in zip(*[iter(splitted)]*2):
    print(os.path.join(path, x, y))

# some_path/own1/own1Add
# some_path/own2/ownAdd2                                          
# some_path/own3/ownAdd
```

**EDIT** (using function as requested):

```
import re
import os

path = 'some_path'
x = 'own1;own1Add*own2;ownAdd2*own3;ownAdd'

def cleanAndMakeSubfolder(x):
    path_list = []
    splitted = re.split(';|\*',x)
    for x, y in zip(*[iter(splitted)]*2):
        path_list.append(os.path.join(path, x, y))
    return path_list

print(cleanAndMakeSubfolder(x))
```

Note that the function returns a list and you can access each item simply by index.

Comment: Not working.  trying to get this in a function `def cleanAndMakeSubfolder(x) :
    splitted = re.split(';|\*',x)
    #print splitted

    for x, y in zip(*[iter(splitted)]*2):
        return x,y

print  cleanAndMakeSubfolder(x)`

Comment: Please do not `return` from function. When you `return`, you only get the first `x`, `y` value. Function exits after that. Is it necessary that you should use a function?

Comment: yes because of lots cleaning and replacing required in x string coz it would be name of folder. so that. in reality `x = Abdul gaffer Dhillon;158 bexer Road, Bexley,  London DA5 1BT*Abdul khan Dhillon;5852 Blendon Road, Bexley, Greater Land, DA5 1BT`

Comment: Can you have a look now?

Comment: Will let you know tomorrow. Thanks

Comment: It works but I just want to `return x,y`.  I tried based on your code. but it still return only records `('own1', 'own1Add')`.

Comment: You should understand what `return` does. When you do `return x, y`, you exit from function at the end of first iteration of the `for` loop. What do you get at the end of first iteration? - the first record `('own1', 'own1Add')`. That is returned to the function caller. No go back to the function again. That's why I introduced a list - `path_list`. So you will appending everything before returning. You get `[(..,..), (..., ...)....]`.